# Why does Kyle Simpson's OLOO approach feel like going against the Typescript current?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Disclaimer: this might be a knee jerk post. Typescript Newbie alert! Bit of a rant as well

I was just trying out the OLOO approach from the YDKJS series of books in a Typescript+Node context.

```js
// what I'd like to write - valid JS

let Account = {
  get id(){
    return this._id;
  },
  get name(){
    return this._name;
  },
  init(id, name){
    this._id = id;
    this._name = name;
  }
}

let TypedAccount = {
  identify(){
    console.log(`This is ${this.name}'s ${this._type} account`);
  },
  init_L2(type){  // avoid collision with base#init
    this._type = type;
  }
}
Object.setPrototypeOf(TypedAccount, Account);

function createAccount(id, name, type){
  let instance = Object.create(TypedAccount);
  instance.init(id, name);
  instance.init_L2(type);
  return instance;
}

let o1 = createAccount(101, 'Tom', 'Savings'),
o2 = createAccount(102, 'Jerry', 'Current');
console.log (o1.identify());
console.log (o2.identify());
```

The primary allure of OLOO was its simplicity. But I'm having to help out / placate the Typescript compiler by writing more code; code which I don't have to write with the class based approach.

1. For every type like Account, I need to declare a matching interface IAccount so that the client usages can be checked/auto completion. I can (am) cheat by using the **any** escape route.
2. TS will complain about usage of undeclared fields so I need to define all the fields & their types before I access them with **this.field**. Not much effort but still. e.g. _id :  defaultValue;
3. Specifying type information in object literals. If an object has a map [strings => numbers], I use a nested object. However TS wants to know the type of the key and the value. So I need to create an interface to decorate the field

```js
interface IMapStringsToNumbers {
   [ key: string ]: number;
}

// 
let Account = {
   _holdings : <IMapStringsToNumbers> {}
```

Maybe the last 2 have nothing to do with OLOO. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Regarding "*avoid collision with base#init*", why don't you just write `init(id, name, type) { super.init(id, name); this._type = type; }`?

Answer (score 3):

When you do `class Account` in TypeScript, you create two things at once:

- a compile-type entity `Account` which is the type of instances of the Account class
- a run-time entity (variable) `Account` which is the class itself (== constructor in Javascript)

with all the necessary wiring in place, i.e. it's already known that `new Account` <sub>variable</sub> returns something of the `Account`<sub>type</sub>.

When you do `let Account = ...` you only create a variable and are left on your own with types. Typescript cannot (and probably never will) track your prototype assignments and infer that `Account` and `TypedAccount` are somehow related.

On a subjective note, I wouldn't call "simple" a pattern that requires you to write

```
init_L2(type){  // avoid collision with base#init
```

or

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(TypedAccount, Account)
```

Bottom line: don't do that. Use classes.